# Magento: get final product price given arbitrary customer group

Tags: magento

Let's say a customer is in group A and for the group A a final price of a product is 10$. Now, in a module I need to find out what price he would get if he was in another group B. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used the following solution after some digging in Mage. Please let me know if this solution is problematic (so far it is working well though). Given a quote item:

```
    $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
    $qty = $quoteItem->getQty();

    $product->setCustomerGroupId($targetGroup->getId());
    $price = $product->getPriceModel()->getFinalPrice($qty, $product);
```